# How to uninstall two applications at a time in Windows System?

Tags: operating-systems, windows-11

I need to uninstall 2 Programs/Applications from the Application Wizard (Control Panel).

[image: Image. A screenshot of the Windows Control Panel, Programs, Programs and Features window. A number of installed applications are shown. Three groups of application icons are marked with a red square, two application icons to a group]

When I try to uninstall the nonrelated application to the current uninstalling application also, I'm getting this dialogue box:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Windows Programs and Features dialog box, stating Please wait until the current program is finished uninstalling or being changed]

May I Know that We can uninstall more than one application from the application wizard in the Windows OS?

Comment: Uninstall one after the other?

Comment: Think of it like a toilet - if someone else is in there, you're just going to have to wait ;)

Comment: The message is clear : "Please wait until the current program is finished uninstalling or being changed." Why not do what it says?

Comment: I typically perform a reset when I get that error dialog.  You cannot uninstall two applications at the same time on Windows.  You can uninstall one application, allow that process to finish, and uninstall any number of applications there after (allowing each one to be uninstalled of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstallation systems only allow one program to be uninstalled at a time for a reason.

You say that they are unrelated, but you have no idea what shared dll files or other parts may actually be common between them. It is common place for programs to use a similar set of shared libraries to do things like common network tasks or drawing windows.

What you think of as unrelated may actually have shared libraries or files in common. When uninstalling one program it may check if other programs could be using the libraries and if not it would remove it.

Doing multiple uninstalls at the same time could break functionality between shared resources and cause something that "seems" unrelated to break other programs.

You are making system wide changes during uninstalls. As a result the default it to be defensive and only allowing one program to make changes at a time so as to avoid clashes and conflicts.

Comment: Yes, I Know that some common libraries or packages is used by some other applications. I came to scenarios like uninstalling the VS 2019, SQL Server Management Studio, Postman, few other dev tools so for the fast working purpose, I thought to uninstall multiple at a time. But on your explanation, got clarity! Thank you!